# Using Robotiumin how to check or make a test case to check the network connection availability in android?

Tags: android, robotium, network-connection

I am new in android testing I am using Robotium for testing purpose and I have a scenario where I need to check is the network (WiFi, 3G, 2G)connection is available or not, so how can i write a test case for this. Please help to solve this..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

You'll need these in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I personally had to run a specific check to see if the user could access my server (Possibility of firewall blocking, or the user having only a local connection)

Good Luck!!

Comment: it's work fine adding activity instance like this...ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);! thanks..